# ¿Qué debo hacer para poder ejecutar : dev_appserver.py 'google cloud sdk'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

Estoy tratando de utilizar **google cloud**, para poder subir mis aplicaciones, pero al momento de ejecutar el script; `dev_appserver.py` ., para conectarme con gcloud. Estoy aprendiendo a programar en **Python**, y es un curso que sigo de platzi, de verdad disculpen si no entiendo muy bien, me lanza el siguiente error en windows:

```
(venv) C:\Termporal\appengine_contact_serever>dev_appserver.py . Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py", line 13, in <module>
from bootstrapping import bootstrapping   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 46, in <module>
from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import update_manager   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 35, in <module>
from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\yaml.py", line 32, in <module>
from typing import Any, AnyStr, Generator, IO, Iterable, Optional, Union  # pylint: disable=unused-import, for pytype   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\typing\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from typing.python3.typing import *   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\typing\python3\typing.py", line 1347, in <module>
class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\typing\python3\typing.py", line 1003, in __new__
self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

Comment: ¿Por casualidad usas Python 3.7? Ha habido cambios en el módulo `abc`, es posible que google-cloud-sdk no soporte por ahora esta versión. Prueba con un entorno con Python 3.6.

Comment: dale gracias, lo hare y comentare al respecto

Comment: buenas noches, ya probe y ahora si ejecuto el comando arriba descrito, pero ahora al acceder http://localhost:8000, me dice que tengo este error:     from gooogle.appengine.ext import vendor
ImportError: No module named gooogle.appengine.ext
INFO     2018-08-23 18:44:09,084 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 2292

Comment: por lo que entiendo como prinicipiante es que no pudo importar del archivo .py que cree con el nombre de appengine_config.py, cierto? porfavor seria de gran ayuda tus conocimientos... gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Desde hace un tiempo, dev_appserver sólo corría con la versión 2.7 de python. Trata de usar una versión que dev_appserver soporte. Creo que actualmente también soporta 3.7 o 3.6.

Trata de correr tu archivo con la versión de python especificada.

Por cierto, respecto a la duda en el comentario que publicaste, para correr una *third party library* necesitas utilizar pip e instalar el módulo en una carpeta (por lo general se le llama "lib") con `pip install tu_modulo -t lib`

Y dentro de un archivo llamado appengine_config.py escribes lo siguiente.

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
```